# Ink.image not showing when used in a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The following code shows image

```dart
Ink.image(
  image: AssetImage('some_image'),
)
```

but if I wrap it in a `Column`, it neither shows the image nor any error.

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage('some_image'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried it, it's working for me may be try wrapping that with IntrinsicHeight widget

Comment: @MohanSaiManthri I tried that but didn't work, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

You should add InkWell as the child parameter to Ink along with the `onTap` parameter to make it work.

```
Ink.image(
    image: const AssetImage("assets/slider/2.jpg"),
    height: 200,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    child: InkWell(
        onTap: (){},
    ),

),
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your widget with Material like this:

```
 Material(
            child: Ink.image(
              image: AssetImage('some_image'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: There's no benefit of wrapping it in `Material`. Even if you remove that and give just height it works (which I already tried) but the question is why does it not work if I don't give it a specific height.

Comment: I also tried this/ if you use Ink.image in Column this will not work even with height. but when you wrap your ink.image with Material then everything will works fine

Comment: I'm not sure why it won't work with just height. It does work. There's no need to introduce `Material` widget because we're already have one throught the ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(
  children: [
Container(child:
    Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage('some_image'),
    ),
    ),

  ],
)
```

Comment: Sorry but it won't really do anything.